# Using Entity Framework Code First with or without database generation

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

We have a couple of large, mature apps installed in hundreds of medical clinics.  These apps are built using Windows Forms and WPF and although we host the database for some of them, the majority of our clients have a local install of the database.

We are in the planning stages of rebuilding our application on the ASP.NET MVC platform using Entity Framework.  We will also be re-architecting our database, but for reference, the current database has about 600 tables and 1900 stored procedures. Although we don't have an official DBA, we have enough DBA skills to build and maintain what we have, so we are capable of designing and building the data model ourselves.  Also, we will continue to have both on-premise and hosted solutions.

Our struggle is with deciding how to use EF.  We're all in agreement that we should use code-first, but some of us think we should build our classes, decorate them with attributes, and allow EF to generate the database for us.  Others think we should design and build the database and then generate code-first POCOs.

Assuming we will have non-CRUD stored procs, triggers, views, stored procs, and user defined functions, is database generation a reasonable approach?  Are there reasons why it might be the preferred approach?  Any good reasons for avoiding it altogether?

Comment: You want to start from classes and use migrations. If you start from the database side you will have problems keeping code and database in sync. Also, when you start from the database you may create something EF does not support - going other way around might make it easier to detect cases like this quicker.

Comment: If you're going to rebuild your database, then go with the database generation approach.  If you are not going to change your database, then it's probably not compelling enough.

Comment: @Pawel - what are the compelling reasons to choose database generation?

Comment: @BrianK.Carroll - your database is going to evolve over time. EF Migrations allows you to evolve the database in a controlled manner. Note that I don't think it's a good idea to let CodeFirst touch the database schema at runtime. With EF migrations you can update/downgrade the database in a controlled manner, review SQL that will be sent to upgrade/downgrade the database and even modify it with needed. To sum up I would use CodeFirst with EF migrations and would disable any initializers. I would not use automatic migrations though (you are loosing the control when you use them).